# Get bitmap of control that extends the client area

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi

I have the following windows form that contains a ListBox with 1000 items.
The ListBox height is so big, it extends/overflows the form client area.
Is there a way to get the bitmap of the whole ListBox (all 1000 items)?

C# has a method for it's controls, [Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), that does indeed capture all items.
I am wondering how to do this in raw c++.

The form:

[image: The form with the ListBox that extends the client area(downwards)]

Comment: Like anything .NET it favors convenience over correctness. [`Control.DrawToBitmap`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4441da5479e7a6f8) simply sends a [`WM_PRINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-print) message to the control, which may or may not work.

Comment: What language are you actually using? Is it C++ or C++/CLI? -- You of course need to send a `WM_PRINT` message to the Control, but also create a GDI+ source DC and destination DC, then `BitBlt` with ROP set to `SRCCOPY`, but this doesn't consider a clipping region, so it may get somewhat more complicated than that. If you're using C++/CLI...